# VSTS Rest API Get WorkItems By Field Value

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way to retrieve a list of work items filtered by some field value?

E.G.:

site/tfs/SomeCollection/wit/workitems?**Status=Done**&asof={datetime}&api-version=1.0

My goal is to use the Rest API to:

- Go to a specific Iteration (including the current one),
- get a list of Backlog Items,
- foreach PBI > Get a list of Done Tasks/Bugs,
- foreach Done Task/Bug > Get information

Then use that information to do whatever I need.

Answer (score 3):

You must do that in 2 or more steps :

1. Use `POST https://{account}.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/[{project}/]_apis/wit/wiql?api-version={version} to get the items using a query with your filter criteria.` (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/wit/wiql)

   Select [System.Id], 
     From  WorkItems
    Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Product Backlog Item' 
      AND [System.IterationPath] = 'Iteration 1'
2. Use `GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/WorkItems?ids=297,299,300&fields=System.Id,System.Links.LinkType,System.WorkItemType,System.Title,System.State&asOf=2014-12-29T20:49:35.357Z&api-version=1.0API`  to get data for each work item returned from step 1.